# Staying signed in to a shared AWS Cloudwatch dashboard

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, dashboard

I have made a dashboard in AWS Cloudwatch. My goal is to display the dashboard on a display in our office. Hence I shared the dashboard using the option "Share your dashboard and require a username and password".

This makes me able to log in and view the dashboard from a non-AWS user, but I am not completely satisfied with the behaviour. My challenges are:

- When logging in there is no option to "keep me signed in". So every day or so I need to sign in again. This is not desirable for an office dashboard.
- Dashboard settings like light vs dark mode and refresh frequency are not stored anywhere, so after each log in (from the non-AWS user) I need to manually adjust these.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of struggle with CloudWatch dashboards I decided to switch to Grafana for my dashboards instead.

Grafana solved all my issues with CloudWatch and we even got more advanced dashboard features as well. Currently, the Grafana free tier also support all our needs, so no extra cost.

Comment: Sad, but same story here.

Comment: Are you using AWS Managed Service for Grafana (AMG) or self-hosted Grafana? I'm using AMG and have exactly the same problem with dashboards in shared spaces where is it not practical to keep logging in every 12 hours. If you have solved it for AMG I would love some info on how.

Comment: None of them. I'm using Grafana hosted by Grafana (Grafana Cloud).